# Combine 2 tables on multiple key values - EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

So, I am having an issue relating to combining 2 tables with 2 corresponding (relative) fields. these fields being: Destination & Date - the primary goal is to combine revenue from the second table with the clicks of the first table (as shown below) once this data has been integrated, a pivot table of the merged will be created.

I have tried multiple approaches to create this relationship but the data is being skewed & I am out of all thinkable options

The first table, for example:

```
Table 1:    
Date         Destination  Clicks    
2019/04/05   a place      938
```

The second table:

```
Date        Destination  Value    
2019/04/05  a place      £9382
2019/04/05  a place      £2000
```

The merger table should read:

Merger Table:

```
 Date          Destination   Clicks  Value
+2019/04/05    a place       938     £11382 ( sum of both bookings ) 
 -2019/04/05   a place               £9382
 -2019/04/05   a place               £2000
```

I have attempted to consolidate the data, but my knowledge of this process is not as expansive as I would hope at the moment, although it is something I am planning to learn!

Any help would very much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a pivot table with 'totals before'...

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "totals before" - could you elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH`?

Comment: I've heard that VLOOKUP() was made redundant by table power-queries, if you are suggesting it, though, it may be worth a try!